# Is there a general formula for look-and-say sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

**1, 11, 21, 1211, 111221, 312211, 13112221, 1113213211, 31131211131221...**

As you probably know, this is called "look-and-say sequence".
Personally I just wonder: does this sequence have a general mathematical non-recurrent formula for nth term?

As a comparison, for Fibonacci numbers (1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89...) we have Binet's formula:
F(n) = (1/√5) * {[(1 + √5)/2]^n – [(1 – √5)/2]^n}.

So does it exist or not?
If there's no formula, then OK, fine, but an additional question appears: is there a way to prove it?

Comment: Did you check [Look and Say sequence](https://oeis.org/A005150)  in 
The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences?